# pg_dump: demasiados argumentos en la línea de órdenes - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Quiero agregar una opción en mi software en donde el administrador pueda generar un backup de la base de datos, abriendo la consola me es suficiente agregando esta linea de comando:

```
pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\03-02-2021.backup" mydb
```

Pero cuando lo trato de colocar dentro del software que esta desarrollado en java no puedo ingresar la contraseña, según la documentación, el parámetro `-W` seria para la contraseña, pero cuando coloco `-W my_password` me sale el siguiente error:

> pg_dump: demasiados argumentos en la línea de órdenes - PostgreSQL

```
try {
        final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process process = runtime.exec("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W my_password -F c -b -v -f \"C:\\Users\\pc1\\Desktop\\my_db.backup\" my_db");
    } catch (final IOException iOException) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + iOException.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se produjo un error, vuelve a intentarlo.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Cómo lo estás poniendo "dentro del software"? Debes añadir el código relevante para saber cómo lo estás intentando y poder tener más idea de por qué falla

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Si le das -W y pones la contraseña en la línea de comandos, va a dar ese error. -W espera preguntar de forma interactiva por la contraseña.

Tienes que crear un archivo `~/.pgpass` que contenga algo como:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

o fijar una variable de entorno en la terminal donde se ejecuta el software

```
SET PGPASSWORD=<password>
```

Comment: Y tengo que especificar la ruta del archivo?

Comment: Al ejecutar pg_dump, el paquete busca el archivo en ubicaciones habituales. Con ponerlo en el home del usuario que corre el programa, debería bastar

Comment: Funciona pero no como esperaba ya que me pide que ingrese la contraseña. Esta es la ruta y el nombre de mi archivo: `C:\Users\pc1\pgpassword.pgpass`, y dentro del archivo esta la siguiente linea: `localhost:5432:mydb:postgres:mypassword`, y para el comando seria: `pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W -F c -b -v -f "C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\my_backup.backup" mydb`

Answer (score 0):

No pude encontrar una solución exclusivamente para agregar la contraseña en la linea de comandos, así que opte por cambiar el código para generar el backup de la siguiente manera:

```
try {
        if (nameBackup == null || nameBackup.trim().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Selecciona la ruta e ingresa el nombre de la copia de seguridad.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/" + "pg_dump.exe", "-f", nameBackup, "-F", "c", "-Z", "9", "-v", "-o", "-h", "localhost", "-U", "postgres", "NOMBRE_BD");
            processBuilder.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", "TU_PASSWORD");
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            final Process process = processBuilder.start();
            final InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String log;
            while ((log = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(log);
            }

            if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Copia de seguridad generada.", "SIET", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se produjo un error, vuelve a intentarlo.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    } catch (final IOException iOException) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + iOException.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se produjo un error, vuelve a intentarlo.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GenerarCopiaSeguridad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se produjo un error, vuelve a intentarlo.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva.